# How to avoid InexactError when computing row of Pascals Triangle

Tags: julia

I wrote a function that computes a row of Pascals Triangle.

```
function calc_row(s, prev::Int64, num::Int64, den::Int64)
    c = 1
    next_num = num
    next_den = den

    if prev > 0
        c = convert(Int64, round(prev * (num / den)))

        next_num = num - 1
        next_den = den + 1
    end

    s = push!(s, c)

    if next_num > 0
        calc_row(s, c, next_num, next_den)
    else
        s
    end
end

function row(r)
    s = []
    calc_row(s, 0, r, 1)
end
```

With bigger inputs, like `row(392)` it dies with:

```
ERROR: LoadError: InexactError()
 in calc_row(::Array{Any,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /var/tmp/148-3.julia:17
 in calc_row(::Array{Any,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at /var/tmp/148-3.julia:26 (repeats 10 times)
 in row(::Int64) at /var/tmp/148-3.julia:34
 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
 in include_from_node1(::String) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:262
 in _start() at ./client.jl:318
 in _start() at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
while loading /var/tmp/148-3.julia, in expression starting on line 37
```

The offending line is:

```
c = convert(Int64, round(prev * (num / den)))
```

How can I avoid this error while still working with integers when computing an entry in the triangle?

Comment: Try `c = prev * div(num, den)`. This keeps everything integer and avoids rounding. Also, `div(num, den)` can be written nicely as `num ÷ den` with `\div<tab>` in the REPL

Comment: @DanGetz that leads to wrong results, like `[1,3,3,0]` for the 3rd row.

Comment: Then, maybe something else is messing the calculation. In any case, going to floating-point is not the way. Perhaps using BigInt is.

Comment: I expect that the algorithm could be improved, but does `((prev * num) / den) ` make things work better? Is there a need for rounding or converting if this is used?

Comment: @rickhg12hs with `((prev * num) ÷ den)`, you get `[1,3,3,1]` as expected. And `row(BigInt(392)` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, the code in the question is correct. To do large row number BigInts are better because Int64 is not enough to hold such numbers. Additionally, floating-point numbers for integer calculations are a source of trouble and rounding errors. So, a little touched up version:

```
function calc_row(s, prev, num, den)
    c = one(den)
    next_num = num
    next_den = den
    if prev > 0
        c = (prev * num) ÷ den
        next_num = num - 1
        next_den = den + 1
    end
    s = push!(s, c)
    return next_num > 0 ? calc_row(s, c, next_num, next_den) : s
end

function row{T}(r::T)
    s = Vector{T}(0)
    calc_row(s, zero(T), r, one(T))
end
```

And `row(BigInt(392))` gives:

```
393-element Array{BigInt,1}:
                             1
                           392
                         76636
                       9962680
                     968870630
                   75184360888
                 4849391277276
               267409290432648
             12869072102071185
            549080409688370560
          21029779691064592448
         730306894726061301376
       23187243907552446318688
      677780975759225353930880
    18348499272339029224271680
   462382181662943536451646336
 10894880155433107077641916792
                             ⋮
 10894880155433107077641916792
   462382181662943536451646336
    18348499272339029224271680
      677780975759225353930880
       23187243907552446318688
         730306894726061301376
          21029779691064592448
            549080409688370560
             12869072102071185
               267409290432648
                 4849391277276
                   75184360888
                     968870630
                       9962680
                         76636
                           392
                             1
```

Comment: Oh super nice, thanks a lot! I didn't think about the difference between BigInt and Int64, but it's obvious. Much better code also.